# Construction of tensor product explanation

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

On this webside

http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf

on page 9, they state, that every element i $F_R(M\times N)$ can be written of a finite sum. My question is why? On page 7 they define it a enormous free vectorspace, whose basis is indexed by $(m,n)$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition the free module $F_R(S)$ over a set $S$ is the module which elements are formal *finite* sum of elements of $S$, with coefficient in $R$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you also please explain, why they can conclude that every element in $F(M\times N)/D$ Can be written as a linear combination of those element. Doesn't it require that the map is surjective?

Comment: I don't understand your question. By definition $M \otimes_R N = F(M \times N)/D$ is the quotient of the module $F(M \times N)$ by some relations. Thus you have a surjective map $F(M \times N) \to M \otimes_R N$ by definition, and the kernel of this map is precisely the relation, i.e the elements of $D$.

Comment: @StenHansen : if you want more details you can tell me which points are not clear

Comment: Thanks, sir! Really a lot of thanks

Comment: You made it all clear!

Comment: Perfect then, you're welcome !